# How to delete replication document for apache couchdb

Tags: database, curl, couchdb, replication

I need to remove a replication document from the replicator db from couchdb, as mentioned by their documents. However I didn't find any sample curl used to delete the replication document. I have tried:

```
curl -vX DELETE -H "Content-type:application/json" http://localhost:5984/_replicator/33e6ca194de0f30420d15ecfea8b2f21
```

But the result is:

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

What would be the proper curl syntax for deleting the replication document? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `33e6ca194de0f30420d15ecfea8b2f21` is the replication_id, i have also tried with the full id: `33e6ca194de0f30420d15ecfea8b2f21+continuous` both didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the result of this HTTP request: `GET /_replicator/_all_docs`?

Comment: [
  {
    "pid": "<0.25906.12>",
    "checkpoint_interval": 5000,
    "checkpointed_source_seq": 16,
    "continuous": true,
    "doc_id": null,
    "doc_write_failures": 0,
    "docs_read": 4,
    "docs_written": 4,
    "missing_revisions_found": 4,
    "progress": 100,
    "replication_id": "33e6ca194de0f30420d15ecfea8b2f21+continuous",
    "revisions_checked": 8,
    "source": "sessions",
    "source_seq": 16,
    "started_on": 1523292052,
    "target": "https://couchdb:*****@<host ip>:<port>/sessions/",
    "type": "replication",
    "updated_on": 1523294013
  }
]

Comment: The above is the result from `GET /_active_tasks`. Here is the result from `GET /_replicator/_all_docs`:
{"total_rows":1,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"_design/_replicator","key":"_design/_replicator","value":{"rev":"1-5bfa2c99eefe2b2eb4962db50aa3cfd4"}}
]} I'm not able to see the replication task in `_replicator` table, is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a replication document by posting a request to `(POST) http://localhost:5984/_replicate`
The request body looks like

```
{
    "id": "your_id_with_+continuous",
    "cancel": true
}
```